# HtmlImageElement - how to get image type if its src doesn't have extension

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to get image type (gif, png, jpeg, etc.) with src like this?

```
<img src="http://d1aviatl7dpuhg.cloudfront.net/image/url/64/aHR0cDovL3BpeGNtc2FkbWluLnBpeGFibGUuY29tL3dwLWNvbnRlbnQvdXBsb2Fkcy8yMDE1LzA3L3NoYXJrLmpwZw==">
```

or created by `new Image()` constructor.

Haven't found anything helpful in W3 specs.

I guess that a separate "XHR get src" is sort of a solution, but maybe there is a better way?

Update: all sorts of XRHs are failing because of CORS, so ajax won't work here.

Comment: What do you mean by "image type"? Mime type?

Comment: Would be great to have the Mime type, but the part which is usually a file extension is also enough (gif, png, jpeg, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats).

Comment: HTML5 only: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/determine-an-images-type-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=HF-5p1W7cQC

Comment: @somethinghere I don't have `<input type="file" />` with a File list

Comment: I don't think you need an input to use filereader, but I have used it once a long time ago.

Comment: FileReader needs either a File or a Blob https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL `<img>` doesn't provide any of those

Comment: Hmm in that case, yeah, that won't work.

Comment: If they hadn't block XMLHttpRequest on your particular example, you would have been able, with an `xhr.responseType='blob'` to get the `xhr.response.type`.

Comment: @Kaiido yes, that's what I mentioned as a probable way. Just need to know if there is a better approach, without making extra request.

Comment: Well if you do this request before the img has loaded, you can make a single request.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.. So the algorithm is 1) `window.stop();` 2) collect all images srcs 3) xhr them 4) on success get mime types 5) update images with binary data or blob urls (or just rely on cache) ? Is there another way to do the request before the img has loaded?

Comment: I would store the URLs to an array then do the getMimeType thing, and then finally populate the <img> 's src with response. But it sounds like you already have some code you need to work with, so maybe your way is better.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for your suggestions! However, I receive already generated html with image tags, I can't generate array of srcs before this. Will continue searhing..

Comment: Also, even if I'm also wondering if there is a solution for this, it may help your particular case to know why you do need this info. (e.g If it's just to know it, you can check it in developer tools, in the network tab, and if a browser plugin is a possibility, you might be able to catch this info too)

Comment: I need this to show image validations / different features based on type, it definitely goes beyond devtools.

Answer (score 13):

**The following works when run in an extension (which doesn't have CORS restrictions)**

I've been exploring this same question, what works is the following:

1. Download the image from the given image `src` as a blob
2. The blob will have the image type in the property `blob.type`

Code sample (with async/await and fetch API):

```
async function getImageBlob(imageUrl) {
    const response = await fetch(imageUrl)
    return response.blob()
}

const blob = await getImageBlob("http://path.to.image.com")
blob.type // Image Content-Type (e.g. "image/png")
```

Comment: It's been a while, but I think extensions may also currently be subjected to CORS

Answer (score 2):

http://www.andygup.net/easily-find-image-type-in-javascript/

I think you may get some help from this page.

Comment: I don't have <input type="file" /> with a File list, please look through the conversation above